# Symplectomorphism, intuitive interpretation.

Tags: intuition, mathematical-physics, symplectic-geometry

What is an intuitive way to think about symplectomorphisms? A symplectomorphism between two symplectic spaces is a map $(M_1, \omega_1)\xrightarrow{\phi} (M_2,\omega_2)$ such that for the pullback $\phi^*\omega_2=\omega_1$. But how to think about $\phi$? What would it typically represent in classical mechanics?

Answer (score 1):

You might have heard them called "canonical transformations" or "contact transformation",they are changes of coordinates that don't change the form of Hamilton's equations of motion.

Comment: Does it goes both ways? If a transformation doesn't change the form of Hamilton's equation it has to be a symplectomorphism?

Comment: Yes. For a more precise discussion regarding terminology (some people don't consider arbitrary symplectomorphisms to be canonical transformations, others do) see:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/367275/poisson-brackets-property-as-necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-transformat

or

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374095/can-any-symplectomorphism-be-called-a-canonical-transformation